# DropBox synchronization technique

Tags: c#, synchronization, dropbox

I am currently developing an application using dropbox c# API.

DropBox is able to capture changes on their server and also the changes in their client almost immediately.

What technique they use to synchronize this 2 replicas?

Wish someone can provide me some clue to start with, I try to avoid the timer base synchronization.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what they use. But you can use filesystemwatcher from c#. That will allow you to catch a file change event. It is not the easiest thing to work with, but simple to use.

To make sure that old revisions of the file to not overwrite the new, I guess they use a revision counter, which is often the case.

To identify if the file is changed from the current stored file, I imagine they may use a number of checks

```
if (local[file.name].size != server[file.name].size)
{
    file.changed = true;
}
else if (local[file.name].md5 != server[file.name].md5)
{
    file.changed = true;
}
else
{
    file.changed = false;
}
```

Comment: I understand this part, what I don't understand is how the client knows the files are changed in server side. Dropbox client is able to detect the changes on server almost immediately, and similar technology I can use?

Comment: Filesystemwatcher will detect a even on the file-system, like the change of a file. That is more than likely what is being used. The other guy said the exact same thing. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: I should change my question: how to detect server changes immediately?

Comment: If you want to detect if there is a server change use the same method as direct push. Have the client connect to the server. And send a message to the client from the server using that open socket on the event of a change.

Comment: yes, do you have any code to refer to? Or any reference that I can view? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For client changes, they might use file system watcher. If there is a change in dropbox folder, they ll trigger the API to update the drop box server.

I am not sure about the server side changes, But there should be some timer mechanism to poll the server to see the changes..

Comment: if they using timer mechanism, means it polls almost every seconds. Is there any technology that similar like push mail, but is for protocol other than email?

Comment: It doesnt have to be every seconds, something like AJAX COMET long polls.. client will initiate a connection, and server will only respond if there is a change. So the client initiate next poll after retrieving the first response.. something like that.......

Answer (score 0):

For server side changes you have to request "list_folder_continue" in V2 api. It will return list of changes made. Test it using [this](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_list_folder/continue) link.